# Why does FireFox draw outlines so far away from the edge of the div?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Style:

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 14px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 72px;

    background-color: #abc;
    color: black;
    outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);

    /* The background image is set inline */
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CF7P2/

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

FireFox:

[image: FireFox]

Why is the FireFox version drawing the margin so far away from the box? Can I stop it from doing so, or can I achieve the same visual result using some other method?

Comment: do you have padding on your image? can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for this

Comment: @Ibu: Done, see my edit. There is no padding on the image, I provided the css.

Comment: interesting, looks like the shadow box act as a padding element;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox, `box-shadow` pushes `outline` outward. (Not sure if by bug or by feature...)

### Method 1

I'd achieve what you're trying to do by wrapping it in another `div`, and applying the `box-shadow` to that.

Like so:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CF7P2/2/)

```
<div id='logo_wrapper'> ... </div>

<!-- -------------------- -->

#logo, #logo_wrapper {
    width: 120px;
    height: 72px;
}
#logo_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
#logo {
    background-color: #abc;
    color: black;
    outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);

    /* The background image is set inline */
}
```

### Method 2

You can use `outline-offset` and a Firefox CSS hack if you do not wish to use the wrapper `div`. Now, please do not ask why I used `21px` instead of `15px`; I got to that value by testing... it *should have* worked with `15px`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CF7P2/3/)

```
body {
    background-color: #444;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 14px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 72px;

    background-color: #abc;
    color: black;
    outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);

    /* The background image is set inline */
}
#logo, x:-moz-any-link {
    outline-offset: -21px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! Would you mind elaborating a bit on what `x:-moz-any-link` does though, and why that style isn't affecting Chrome?

Comment: It's just a browser hack, Chrome ignores the `-moz-` tag so I suspect it ignores the entire rule. They're just quirks in the browsers that are exploited for targeting. You can find more on them [on this blog](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/).